# How to copy value from .then condition to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to copy the value of **data** to handleError().

```
    handleErrors(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            let errors = {};
            console.log(response)
            errors.password = 'Invalid Credentials.';
            errors.password = 'Only '+ response.detail +' wrong attempts left.';   
            stopLoading();
            this.setState({ errors });
        }
        return response;
    }
```

As you can see **handleError()** has get value from upper **.then** condition, so how to I get the value from the other **.then** to **handleError**.

```
                .then(response => this.handleErrors(response))
                .then((response) => response.json())
                
                .then((data) => { 
                    console.log(data.detail)
```

**data.detail** is showing the right answer perfectly and I need to copy it to **handleError**, so it can be like-

```
    handleErrors(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            let errors = {};
            console.log(response)
                    console.log(data.detail)
            errors.password = 'Invalid Credentials.';
            errors.password = 'Only '+ data.detail +' wrong attempts left.';   
            stopLoading();
            this.setState({ errors });
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Thank you, I am not very proficient so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: If the response isn't ok, how do expect to get data from it?

Comment: Why can you not call the handleError where ever you want?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to get the data from response but console was showing no output.

Comment: I used the below condition and the code is working fine. The handleError was showing error when I'd tried to get the value of data.

Comment: You were accessing `response.ok`, which is usually where you check whether fetch failed or not *before* trying to parse its response. If you are also using an `ok` field in your server response, you need to run `.json()` first, so you actually have your server response. If you're processing your own error, you need to make sure your code doesn't then proceed like the request was successful.

Comment: I tried **response.json()** in handleError() but it showed no response, I tried multiple techniques can you tell me the reason why you thinks that below answer will not work

Comment: Again: you need to properly deal with a) the fetch failing completely due to a network error or similar b) the fetch being successful but unsuccessful in the context of your app, like bad login credentials. I'm still not sure which one you're dealing with in your question.

Comment: When the fetch promise is resolved, the result is a Response object. It has an `.ok` property and a  `.json()` method, among others. The order is usually: 1. `const response = await fetch(...);` 2. check `response.ok`, 3. const data = response.json(); 4. check actual server `data`

Comment: Also, the reason why the answer below won't work: the first `then` callback doesn't return anything. Plus, if your question is about handling a network error, `this.handleErrors(data)` will never be even reached

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining everything in details. In this question, i needed to fetch a value ```data.details```, I tried to access it but handleError had only ```response.json()``` which was showing only post request and no data. ``` .then((data) => this.handleErrors(data))``` added data as response so when I wrote ```response.details```, it worked. May I add the full working code in answer with description?

Comment: You are not addressing what I said at all. Why are you checking `response.ok`? Where are you getting this from? Is your server sending back `{ ok: true, details: ...}`?

Comment: I checked ```console.log(response)``` and it shows this output- `Response {type: "basic",` `url: "http://localhost:3000/api/oauth2/token",` `redirected:false,status:401,ok:false, …}`
`body: (...),Headers {},type: "basic",` `url: "http://localhost:3000/api/oauth2/token",__proto__: Response`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your current code looks like

```sh
   .then(response => this.handleErrors(response))
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => { 
                    console.log(data.detail)
```

This is solution I am proposing to you. Just paste **handleError()** where you need

```sh
   .then(response =>  console.log(response))
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => this.handleErrors(data))
```

Comment: This will not work at all. You're passing `data` to handle errors, which is expecting the fetch call's `Response` object.

Comment: I responded based on question

Comment: Regardless of what OP is looking for exactly (handling network errors vs. handling business logic errors), `.then(response =>  console.log(response))` will cause an error